# Jquery Validation with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jquery-validate, capybara

How to write tests for devise login form with jquery validation using capybara with rspec?

I am using rails 4.2.4 & capybara 2.5.0.
I am validating the login form with jquery validation.
I need to test if I kept email or password field blank, it should throw an error.
My sample code is

```
scenario 'throws error on blank email id' do
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  within('.form-fields') do
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: ''
    fill_in 'user[password]', with: 'abcdefgh'
  end

  click_button 'Log In'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Please enter email id'
end
```

My Html code is

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-fields">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.submit "Log In" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My Jquery Validate code is

```
  $('.new_user').validate({
    rules: {
      'user[email]': {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      'user[password]': {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
      }
    },
    messages: {
      'user[email]': {
        required: 'Please enter email id',
        email: 'Please enter a VALID email id'
      },
      'user[password]': {
        required: 'Please enter a password',
        minlength: 'Password should be 8 characters long'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't see any code here that has anything to do with jQuery Validate plugin.  Where is the relevant *rendered* JavaScript and HTML of this form?

Comment: @Sparky updated the question.

Comment: That is not the rendered HTML.  The "rendered" HTML is what is loaded into the browser and what you would see with a "view source" or "DOM".   The rendered HTML is all that matters to JavaScript.